# Auto-connect to saved network after stopping and starting wpa_supplicant.service

Tags: raspbian, wifi, wifi-direct

Board: Raspberry Pi 3 B+

OS: Raspian Stretch (with desktop and recommended software) 2018-11-13

I'm building an application that requires me to temporarily disable the wpa_supplicant service, while I update the wifi remotely.

Steps

- I run 'sudo systemctl stop wpa_supplicant.service'
- I append a wifi network to the wpa_supplicant.conf using a python script
- I run 'sudo systemctl start wpa_supplicant.service'
- I then have to run 'sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd.service', to see a list of available wireless connections again.

The problem is, even though I have a valid network in my wpa_supplicant.conf, it doesn't automatically try to connect at this point. I have to restart the Pi, and then it properly connects to my saved network.

I have tried 'sudo ifconfig wlan0 down' and then 'sudo ifconfig wlan0 up', but that doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Raspbian Stretch doesn't use wpa_supplicant.service.

Comment: I'm stopping the service because I have a docker container that starts up and has it's own wpa_supplicant.service. They conflict. So I let the code run on the docker container, and then once I kill the container, I need the wifi to automatically connect to a saved connection.

Comment: Also, it definitely seems to use wpa_supplicant.service. If you start up a fresh install of the latest Raspian Stretch, and stop wpa_supplicant.service, pkill wpa_supplicant, you will not be able to connect to a wifi connection.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that default Raspbian uses **dhcpcd** for networking. It manages `wpa_supplicant` its own way as a hook and does not respect default service management. So using `systemctl` for wpa_supplicant has no meaning when using **dhcpcd**. `systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service` will mostly show you that it is disabled.

But to manage **wpa_supplicant** online you can use `wpa_cli`. Here are some steps to show how it could be integrated into your application. I have configured `wpa_supplicant` with my default network, but that is just not in range:

```
rpi ~$ wpa_cli -iwlan0 list_networks
network id / ssid / bssid / flags
0       default_Net     any

rpi ~$  iw dev wlan0 link
Not connected.
```

Then add the current network that is just available, to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. I use **bash** instead of **python**:

```
rpi ~$ sudo bash -c 'cat >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf <<EOF
network={
    ssid="current_Net"
    psk="secretPassword"
}
EOF'
```

Now reconfigure **wpa_supplicant**:

```
rpi ~$ wpa_cli -iwlan0 reconfigure
OK

rpi ~$ wpa_cli -iwlan0 list_networks
network id / ssid / bssid / flags
0       default_Net     any
1       current_Net     any     [CURRENT]

rpi ~$  iw dev wlan0 link
Connected to b8:27:eb:86:d0:2d (on wlan0)
        SSID: current_Net
        freq: 2437
        RX: 1746 bytes (12 packets)
        TX: 5134 bytes (35 packets)
        signal: -54 dBm
        tx bitrate: 1.0 MBit/s

        bss flags:      short-slot-time
        dtim period:    2
        beacon int:     100
```

So for your application you only need two steps:

- append a wifi network to the wpa_supplicant.conf using a python script
- run '/sbin/wpa_cli -iwlan0 reconfigure'

Comment: This answer is misleading. Using `dhcpcd` is not a "problem" it is feature - it is a sophisticated network manager. "systemctl has no meaning when using dhcpcd" is just plain wrong as `systemctl status dhcpcd` would show. It is unclear WHY the OP feels the need to disable anything.

Comment: @Milliways `dhcpcd` is an antiquated system that is very bad integrated in modern upcoming operating system management that nearly all linux distributions uses today.

Answer (score 0):

Raspbian Stretch does not normally use wpa_supplicant.service as shown by `systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service`

```
● wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

That is not to say it doesn't use wpa_supplicant as shown by `systemctl status dhcpcd.service`

```
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-03-04 17:23:49 AEDT; 4 days ago
  Process: 354 ExecStart=/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -q -b (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 361 (dhcpcd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
           ├─361 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -b
           └─477 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
```

`dhcpcd` starts `wpa_supplicant` with `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/10-wpa_supplicant`
It is instructive to read the comments in this file:-

```
# Start, reconfigure and stop wpa_supplicant per wireless interface.
# This is needed because wpa_supplicant lacks hotplugging of any kind
```

Raspbian Jessie started `wpa_supplicant` in `/etc/network/interfaces` (although this was done by wpa-conf and I am not sure wpa_supplicant.service was ever invoked).

Normally if you make any changes to `wpa_supplicant.conf` you would restart `dhcpcd`.

NOTE is is possible (and common) to have multiple instances of `wpa_supplicant` running.

Hopefully this answers some of your questions, but from your Comments you are doing something else, which was not in your Question.